# npm start giving error windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed node.js via installer and verified. Now when i run `npm start` command it gives be an error as follows. Any idea how to solve this.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.0
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop\package.json'
5 verbose stack     at Error (native)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop
7 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
8 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
9 error node v0.12.0
10 error npm  v2.5.1
11 error path C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop\package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno -4058
14 error enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop\package.json'
14 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
14 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
15 verbose exit [ -4058, true
```

]
Thanks

Comment: Looks like an authorizations problem. No access on 'C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop\package.json'. Do you run the console as admin?

Comment: Yes, Doing with admin rights. One thing i don't have package.json at C:\Users\vivekdhiman\Desktop\ location.

Comment: Resolved over at the `npm` issue tracker: [npm/npm#9746](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9746)